# displaying members of dictionary depending on key in comboBox

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, combobox

I have a couple of different dictionary-structures that i want to display in a comboBox.

**In JumpType.cs:**

```
public SortedDictionary<int, List<string>> jumpCombination = new SortedDictionary<int, List<string>>();
```

The dictionary structure will look something like this:

```
Key    Values
1      Flygande
       EjFlygande
2      Bak
       Pik
       Test
3      ...
```

I have created two comboBoxes in my UI like this:

```
Select Key:      _____________
                |   ComboBox  |
                --------------      __________
                 _____________      |   OK   |
Select Value:   |   ComboBox  |     ----------
                --------------
```

**In  Form1.cs**

```
 InitializeComponent();
 JumpType jt = new JumpType();
 jt.addjumpCombination(); // populating the dictionary
 if (jt.jumpCombination != null)
 {
    comboBoxJumpComboKey.DataSource = new BindingSource(jt.jumpCombination, null); // Key => null
    comboBoxJumpComboKey.DisplayMember = "Value";
    comboBoxJumpComboKey.ValueMember = "Key";
    comboBoxJumpComboValue.DisplayMember = "Value";
 }
```

How would I go about to select the corresponding values according to the selected key?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: List<string> values = jumpCombination[key]

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your list using the following LINQ query:

```
var selectedValues = jumpCombination
                    .Where(j => j.Key == Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxJumpComboKey.SelectedItem.Value))
                    .Select(a => a.Value)
                    .ToList();
```

Also, selectedValues is a collection of List which is  **Values** in your case

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. SelectedItem.Value is invalid syntax :/

Comment: Strange! Isn't comboBoxJumpComboKey a combo box? What about comboBoxJumpComboKey.SelectedValue? Does that work for you?